# Passing two-dimensional arrays of varying size in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to call a function with a two-dimensional array of variable size as a parameter. In order to do this, I use a template:

```
template <int N, int M>
void move(int (&arr)[M][N]);
```

Now this works fine when I declare the size of the array directly, e.g.:

```
int arr[5][7];
move(arr);
```

But if I get the dimensions in from somewhere else, e.g.:

```
int x, y;
x = 7;
y = 5;
int arr[y][x];
move(arr);
```

The compiler shows this error:

> no matching function for call to 'move(int[((unsigned int)((int)y))][((unsigned int)((int)x))])

... and I don't get it. I'm fairly new to c++ and this may just be me being stupid, and I know multidimensional arrays in c++ are... interesting, but in this case I don't even understand what the problem is. Anyone have an idea?

Edit: I worded the question weirdly, sorry about that - the array itself does not vary its size, but the function should be able to work with arrays of different sizes. The question is why that works when I declare the array's size directly, but not when I declare to parameters for each dimension and then declare the array with those.

Comment: Arrays in C++ have fixed, compile-time constant sizes. There is no such thing as "an array with varying size". It just doesn't exist. Use a `vector` instead, or maybe Boost.multiarray.

Comment: I may have worded that weirdly - the array itself doesn't vary its size, but the function should be able to work with arrays of different sizes. I'll edit that in real quick.

Comment: OK, but note that there is also no such thing as an array (type) with a dynamically determined size. Sorry. You have to manage a dynamic array either manually or through a container such as `std::vector`.

Comment: agree with @KerrekSB, but if you want to use "manual" arrays, at least declare a class to handle them, like `template <class T> class BidimensionalArray` with a backing variable of type `T**`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Well, they exist as compiler extensions in g++. But they aren't part of standard C++, no. If there were 'no such thing' the compiler would give the OP an error when the array is declared. But it gives the error when it attempts to expand the template (which absolutely will not handle non-const parameters) instead. I'm actually kind of impressed it doesn't segfault or something similar when it tries to expand the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well declaring an array with variable bounds like this is an extension in the first place. It's not actually valid standard C++. Secondly, using bare arrays in C++ is frowned upon. You should be using `::std::vector` instead.

The compiler error message is really quite inscrutable. And I'm amused it was able to give you one at all instead of faulting. You are presenting it with an extremely strange case.

Templates parameters have to be compile time constants. They cannot be things whose values might change at runtime. It has to be possible for the compiler to know that the parameters are constant at compile time. This will only happen if the values are actual literal values or named values declared as a `constexpr` or a simple expression involving literals or values declared as `constexpr`.

In the case of your array with variables bounds... Neither of those variables are `constexpr`s, so they could potentially change at runtime. The compiler has no way to know in advance which version of the function to generate.

Answer (score 1):

Because, although you give statically-known values to `x` and `y`, these are both mutable variables and, as such, they still don't fit the criteria for array dimensions. The template function then cannot be instantiated with that oddness.

```
const unsigned int x = 7, y = 5;
```

This would be enough.

Initialising a `const unsigned int` with anything other than statically-known quantities (e.g. literals, as above) would *not* be.

`constexpr` makes array dimension safety easier to guarantee in C++11.